# How to read Windows event viewer .extx file using VB.Net that was saved from another machine

Tags: windows, events, viewer

Trying to read Windows Event Viewer .evtx files that were saved from another machine using VB.net.  All the examples I can find are reading the event log from the local machine.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Without using WMI or Powershell you can use prepared command-line utility.
You can read, export, query data from log-files by **wevtutil**.

Example1:

```
wevtutil qe "c:\folder\exported.evtx" /f:text /lf:true
```

Example2:

```
wevtutil qe "c:\folder\exported.evtx" /c:3 /rd:true /lf:true
```

Call help:

```
wevtutil /?
```

For stdout+stderr reading (from command-line) use something like this on **VB.Net**:

```
NewProcess.Start()
NewProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
NewProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
```